# SyntaxError: Unexpected token b in JSON at position 3

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i am new to MERN framework
try to use postman to test my get and post request. but keep getting this error SyntaxError: Unexpected token b in JSON at position 3
here is my schema -------------------------

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  firstname: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  lastname: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  sex: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  age: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  admin: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true
  }
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model("user", UserSchema);
```

here is my route---------------------

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const User = require("../../models/user");

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  User.find()
    .sort({ age: -1 })
    .then(users => res.json(users));
});

router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const newUser = new User({
    firstname: req.body.firstname
  });

  newUser.save().then(user => res.json(user));
});

module.exports = router;
```

here is my server------------------

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const users = require("./routes/api/users");
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

const db = require("./config/keys").mongoURI;

mongoose
  .connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(() => console.log("MongoDB Connected"))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

app.use("/api/users", users);

const port = 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`server started on port ${port}`));
```

please help!! stuck for whole day

Comment: forgot to post error message erver started on port 5000
SyntaxError: Unexpected token b in JSON at position 3
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parse (/Users/alexcai/ustsv/project1/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:89:19)
    at /Users/alexcai/ustsv/project1/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (/Users/alexcai/ustsv/project1/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
    at done (/Users/alexcai/ustsv/project1/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/Users/alexcai/ustsv/project1/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)

Comment: at which file and line you are getting error ?

Comment: @alexcodecai this looks like the payload that you are sending from frontend is not a valid json so the middleware json parser is spitting that error out. Can you provide the front end part of the code that's sending the request so that we can better help investigate error.

Comment: @EdwardRomero, I just set up my backend, there is not frontend yet, I just wanna use postman to test if my server is working if I send some get request

Comment: @TusharNikam it just said SyntaxError: Unexpected token b in JSON at position 3
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: @alexcodecai can you share the json payload you are sending through postman and whether you are sending it as Body -> raw -> JSON. If you are doing that, then please provide your version of express so that we can better provide feedback on your json body parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `express.json()` for GET routes. So please try moving `app.use(express.json());` to route file before POST request.

Also if you are using express version >= 4, please use `app.use(bodyParser.json())` from `body-parser` package.